# Update user in CASL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, casl

I'm using a very basic [CASL](https://github.com/stalniy/casl) implementation. Unfortunately, the docs aren't that detailed. I have the following code (basically copy-pasted from the docs).

```
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue'
import defineAbilitiesFor  from './ability'

const ability = defineAbilitiesFor({name: 'guest'})
Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability )
```

where `defineAbilitiesFor` is defined as  (in ./ability.js)

```
import { AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability'

function defineAbilitiesFor(user) {
  return AbilityBuilder.define((can, cannot) => {
     can(['read'], 'foo', { username: user.name})
  })
}
```

I know it's possible to update the rules/conditions (i.e. `ability.update([])`). But how do I update the user's information after initializing CASL? (e.g. after the user has logged in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CASL has nothing to do with user. What eventually it cares is only user's permissions. So, after login you need to update rules, basically use `ability.update(myRules)`

In your Login component, after login request to API (or after you receive information about currently logged in user), you need to call `ability.update(defineRulesFor(user))`.

`ability` can be just an empty `Ability` instance. For example:

```
const ability = new Ability([])

function defineRulesFor(user) {
  const { can, rules } = AbilityBuilder.extract()

  can(['read'], 'foo', { username: user.name })

  return rules
}

// Later after login request to API (or after you receive information about currently logged in user)

login() {
  return http.post('/login')
    .then((response) => {
       ability.update(defineRulesFor(response.user))
       // after that Ability instance contains rules for returned user
    }) 
}
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. Sorry, I guess I didn't completely understand the idea behind CASL yet. Thank you!